# Deserialize using Jackson ObjectMapper to Pojo<T>

Tags: java, groovy, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize using ObjectMapper to a POJO and im getting the error:

```
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class LambdaResult<java.lang.Object>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

My Pojo is quite simple

```
   class LambdaResult<T>  {

        LambdaResult() {}

        String Status
        ArrayList<T> Results
    }
```

And my deserialization code is the following

```
 static <T> T Deserialize(final TypeReference<T> type,
                                    final String json) {

            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, type)
        }


 LambdaResult<Object> result =  Serialization.Deserialize(new TypeReference<LambdaResult<Object>>() {},jsonResult)
```

Json example:

```
{"status": "success", "locale": "sg", "results": [{"status": "pending"}]}
```

I come from a C# background so there's something im probably missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload some JSON you are trying to deserialze.

Comment: This is it: {"status": "success", "locale": "sg", "results": [{"status": "pending"}]}

Comment: Try either removing the empty constructor or make it `public`. The default accessor only allows classes in the same package to use it.

Comment: Im using groovy so its public by default. I tried removing it aswell and the result is the same.

Comment: field names and method names should start with a lower case letter.  I doubt Jackson can match `String Status` to `"status": "success"`
.  Also, is this all in Groovy?  When you say POJO, do you mean POGO?

Comment: Besides the capitalizations. It looks like you should be using Map for Results

new TypeReference<LambdaResult<Map>>() {}

which is odd because it is a list of kvpairs. Are you sure Result shouldn't just be a Map in the first place? I would consider not using generics in LambdaResult unless you have a real usecase for it.

Comment: @JohnMercier there are cases i might want to have nested classes, so a simple kvpais won't resolve it for me.

Comment: @tim_yates you are right, but i had FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false. I mean Plain Old Java Object by saying POJO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating and configuring an `ObjectMapper` like this (Java, sorry don't speak Groovy):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

`mapper` in this case should probably be a field in the same class as `Deserialize` method that would then look like:

```
return mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

Explanation for configuration:

1. This `MapperFeature` tells Jackson to match field names in a case insensitive manner. So it will find `String Status` although it doesn't follow Java Beans naming conventions. This is neat in your case but comes with a small performance penalty for transforming a String to lowercase. You can alternatively annotate a field in a class with `@JsonProperty` and specify any JSON field name you want.
2. This tells Jackson to match JSON fiels to Java object fields regardless of field visibility `private`, `public` etc. You may also annotate your class with `@JsonAutoDetect` and specify visibility there. In both cases you don't need to define a constructor but you can keep it if you don't want it to be public.
3. The last one tells Jackson to not fail when encountering fields in JSON that don't exist in your class. In this case `"locale"`.

Comment: Thanks Manos! Actually i've put FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false before seeing your response but somehow it didn't reflect my changes. I didn't know about the other ones, quite good. Thanks